# How to dynamically change data shown on the v-list in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, dynamic-list

I want to dynamically display data on list depending upon the key I select. The list of items can have multiple keys. I want to dynamically choose the data that I want to display onto the list without hard coding the actual key.

```
<template>
  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="500"
  >
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item-group v-model="model">
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :key="i"
        >
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.data_to_display"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      data_to_display: 'name',   // or data_to_display: 'text'
      items: [
        {
          age: 34,
          name: 'abc',
          marks: null
        },
        {
          age: 12, 
          name: '',
          marks: 60
        },
        {
          age: '20,
          name: 'lmn',
          marks: 70
        },
      ],
      model: 1,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

The above list of items has multiple keys. I want to display any one of them name, age or marks depending upon the key I choose from the script

Comment: You have the `item`, just take whatever you want from it. `item[key]`

Comment: Do you mean item[data_to_display] ?

Comment: Thanks it worked... But it is also displaying some blank values  i.e. spaces if one of the objects has an empty values.

Comment: For that you’ll need to make a computed list which filters values out

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly is computed list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Sami commented you can use key to show data, and in computed property filter only ones with values:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      data_to_display: 'name',  
      items: [{age: 34, name: 'abc', marks: null}, {age: 12, name: '', marks: 60}, {age: 20, name: 'lmn', marks: 70 },],
      model: 1,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter(i => i[this.data_to_display]  )
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-card
          class="mx-auto"
          max-width="500"
        >
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item-group v-model="model">
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in filteredItems"
                :key="i"
              >
                <v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title v-text="item[data_to_display]"></v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you think this is a feasible solution as there are 1000s of objects within items array? I tried adding a v-if statement inside <v-list-item-content v-if="item !== null"> but this also didn't work

Comment: @Mrunall Veer hey mate, why not you only filter for items with values, as you can se it works in example?

Comment: Because I will have to iterate the loop 1000 times each time I switch the key. Can I add a v-if statement instead?

Comment: I think when you change the key you are already iterating in v-for in template, so it's the same because you are now connected at `filteredItems` in template

Answer (score 1):

Convert `v-text="item.data_to_display"` to `v-text="item[data_to_display]"` will resolve the issue.

You need to use `brackets` if the property name has special characters. Bracket notation can be quite useful if you want to search for a property's values dynamically.

As in one of the object you have empty value for `name` property, It is showing as blank.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    data_to_display: 'name',
    model: 1,
    items: [{
      age: 34,
      name: 'abc',
      marks: null
    }, {
      age: 12, 
      name: '',
      marks: 60
    }, {
      age: '20',
      name: 'lmn',
      marks: 70
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-card
                class="mx-auto"
                max-width="500"
                >
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item-group v-model="model">
              <v-list-item
                           v-for="(item, i) in items"
                           :key="i"
                           >
                <v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title v-text="item[data_to_display]"></v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```